# multiple promise in async await

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm facing a confusion and would appreciate some clarification or a reference article explaining the behavior observed in the following code snippets.

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
  }, 20000);
});

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
  }, 10000);
});


async function handlePromise() {
  try {
    console.log("Hello World!!");
    const val = await p1;
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript");
    console.log(val);

    const val2 = await p2;
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript 2");
    console.log(val2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
handlePromise();
```

In this case, the program prints "Hello World!!" and then waits for 20 seconds. After the waiting period, both p1 and p2 parts are printed simultaneously. I'm trying to understand why there is a simultaneous execution of both promises.

but

for this peice of code

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
  }, 10000);
});

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
  }, 20000);
});


async function handlePromise() {
  try {
    console.log("Hello World!!");
    const val = await p1;
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript");
    console.log(val);

    const val2 = await p2;
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript 2");
    console.log(val2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }


}

handlePromise();
```

In this scenario, after printing "Hello World!!", the program prints the p1 part after a 20-second delay, followed by the p2 part after a 10-second delay. I'm seeking an explanation for this specific timing behavior.

Any insights or references to articles explaining the underlying asynchronous nature of JavaScript promises would be greatly helpful. Thank you!

tried to seek explanation of a behavior of multiple promise, async await

Comment: `I'm trying to understand why there is a simultaneous execution of both promises.` because the setTimeout starts when you `const p1 =` / `const p2 =`  not when you await them - so, since p2 resolves after 10 seconds, waiting 20 seconds for p1 to resolve means p2 is already resolved

Comment: `In this scenario, after printing "Hello World!!"` your timings are all wrong. p1 prints out after 10 seconds and p2 after another 10 seconds

Comment: @JaromandaX can be elaborate behind the scene in JS for the first snippet of code where p1 timeout after 20 sec and p2 after 10 secs

Comment: setTimeout times out after the given milliseconds, and runs the given callback ... that's what it does "behind the scenes" - it does not stop other things from running, otherwise `Hello World` would not be output immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that `await` doesn't block the javascript interpreter. While you're awaiting other things can still happen and other pieces of code can still execute before your awaited event completes. The `await` keyword only blocks your function.

First, both cases are identical: the task scheduled to finish after 10 seconds always completes after 10 seconds and the task scheduled to finish after 20 seconds always completes after 20 seconds. Always. Neither tasks will take 30 seconds to complete because you've started both in parallel.

To see that this is true let's remove `await` in our test code:

```
function handlePromise() {
    p1.then((val) => {
        console.log("Namaste JavaScript");
        console.log(val);
    }).catch((error) =>  {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    })

    p2.then((val2) => {
        console.log("Namaste JavaScript 2");
        console.log(val2);
    }).catch((error) =>  {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    })
}
handlePromise();
```

You will see in scenario 1 p2 completes first then p1 completes 10 seconds after that and in scenario 2 the opposite happens. Both timers run in parallel.

In your code you are basically doing this:

```
function handlePromise() {
    p1.then((val) => {
        console.log("Namaste JavaScript");
        console.log(val);
        return p2;
    }).then((val2) => {
        console.log("Namaste JavaScript 2");
        console.log(val2);
    }).catch((error) =>  {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    })
}
handlePromise();
```

So in scenario 1 p2 completes before p1 but we don't handle the result of p2 until p1 completes. So when p1 completes the result of p2 is also immediately processed because it was completed 10 seconds ago.

To get the result that I think you're expecting don't start the `setTimeout` before you want it to start:

```
function startP1 () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
    }, 20000);
  });
}

function startP2 () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Promise Resolved Value!!");
    }, 10000);
  });
}


async function handlePromise() {
  try {
    console.log("Hello World!!");
    const val = await startP1();
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript");
    console.log(val);

    const val2 = await startP2();
    console.log("Namaste JavaScript 2");
    console.log(val2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
handlePromise();
```

#### PS:

Another thing to remember is that the callback to the Promise constructor is synchronously executed, not asynchronous. We can see that this is the case by running the following code:

```
console.log('hello');
new Promise((ok,fail) => {
  console.log('cruel');
});
console.log('world');
```

The above code prints:

```
hello
cruel
world
```

not `hello, world, cruel`. The function you pass to the Promise constructor is executed synchronously.